# Using Account as Entry Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, person-accounts, entry-criteria

We are using Person Account at Salesforce. I want every time the field '# of children' is changed - the account will enter the journey.
I choose Account as the object, I have 3 options for 'Select who to inject '

[image]

I've tried choosing each one of them, and then at the Entry Criteria I chose 'IsCreated' and 'IsUpdated' and chose a field at Account object
[image]

I've updated the # of children at the Account at Salesforce many times but there are no entries to the Journey. anybody knows why?? How to Solve?

Here is the Summary of what @Mocca suggested

[image]

Comment: Which type of field is “# of children”? If this is a formula field, fours it reference fields on other objects than Account?

Comment: What's the API name of the field? (to know whether its a field from PersonAccount or PersonContact).

Comment: JB when the updates field goes from not meeting criteria to meeting criteria. So you would need the criteria to be # of children = x or number of children is not null. A change that does not go from not meet to meet will not inject

Comment: The “# of children” field is number(3,0), not a formula. And it is a field on the Account object. the API name is 'of_children__c'. I've changed the value of the field from '0' to '2'

Answer (score 0):

Macca is completely right and I think his awnser is the easiest way to solve the problem. I have another idea. I don't know if is applicable but maybe what you can do is: create a boolean field in the same object that you used as Entry source and a flow (in process Builder) to change this field from true to false and false to true (oscilating) everytime the number of children ('of_children__c') changes and in the entry criteria you can put this boolean field as a condition.

E.g
of_children__c GREATER THAN 1 AND
(num_of_children_change__c is true OR num_of_children_change__c is false)
[WHEN the record IS UPDATED]

Again, I never tried this before. But I think would be my "second option".